# Как скопировать текст в буфер обмена?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
function CopyToClipboard(containerid) {
if (document.selection) { 
    var range = document.body.createTextRange();
    range.moveToElementText(document.getElementById(containerid));
    range.select().createTextRange();
    document.execCommand("Copy"); 

} else if (window.getSelection) {
    var range = document.createRange();
     range.selectNode(document.getElementById(containerid));
     window.getSelection().addRange(range);
     document.execCommand("Copy");
}}
```

```html
<button id="button1" onclick="CopyToClipboard('copy1')">Click to copy1</button>
<div id="copy1" >Новинка!111</div>

<button id="button2" onclick="CopyToClipboard('copy2')">Click to copy2</button>
<div id="copy2" >Новинка!222</div>
```

Копируется только первый `div`

Comment: Вы можете воспользоваться еще этим методом: ```navigator.clipboard.writeText(text)```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function CopyToClipboard(containerid) {
  if (document.selection) { 
      var range = document.body.createTextRange();
      range.moveToElementText(document.getElementById(containerid));
      range.select().createTextRange();
      document.execCommand("Copy"); 
  
  } else if (window.getSelection) {
      var range = document.createRange();
       range.selectNode(document.getElementById(containerid));
       window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();  
       window.getSelection().addRange(range);
       document.execCommand("Copy");
  }}
```